# Add custom class in header region on drupal 8

Tags: class, drupal, hook, region

I'd like to add custom class in my drupal template, in header region, but it doesn't works.

```html
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'themes/marinenat/templates/layout/page.html.twig' -->
<div class="layout-container">

  <header role="banner">
    

<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'region' -->
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   x region--header.html.twig
   * region.html.twig
-->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'themes/marinenat/templates/layout/region--header.html.twig' -->
<div class="nav">
```

I'd like to add this class after "nav" class di region--header.

Anyone can help me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You already have all you need in the output.

#### Many roads lead to Rome

If `themes/marineat` is you base theme, simply copy `themes/marinenat/templates/layout/region--header.html.twig` into your subtheme's `themes/MYSUBTHEME/templates` directory and edit this file. Flush cache. Done.

If `themes/marinenat` is you custom subtheme simply edit the suggested template file `/themes/marinenat/templates/layout/region--header.html.twig/` and add your class there. Flush cache. Done.

Last but not least you can also add classes to a region from a preprocess function from your `MYSUBTHEME.theme` file or any `MYMODULE.module` file.

```php
/**
 * Implements template_preprocess_region().
 */
function MYTHEME/MYMODULE_preprocess_region(&$variables) {

  if (isset($variables['region']) && $variables['region'] == 'header') {
    $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'MYCLASS';
  }
}
```

---

#### How to pass a string from PHP to Twig

```php
/**
 * Implements template_preprocess_region().
 */
function MYTHEME/MYMODULE_preprocess_region(&$variables) {

  $variables['foo'] = FALSE;

  if (isset($variables['region']) && $variables['region'] == 'header') {       

    // Get the current node.
    $node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');

    if ($node instanceof \Drupal\node\NodeInterface) {

      // Get the node type.
      $node_type = $node->bundle();

      // Do what ever else you need to do to retrieve your class dynamically.
      $variables['foo'] = $node_type;
    }
  }
}
```

Then in your `region--header.html.twig` Twig file it's:

```
{% if foo %}
  <div class="nav {{ foo }}">
    {{ content }}
  </div>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Hello, I add in marinenat.theme preprocess region function and flush cache, but class not appear

Comment: @antoine - What exactly did you add? Did you replace `MYTHEME/MYMODULE_preprocess_region` with `marineat_preprocess_region`? If it's still not working edit the template `/themes/marinenat/templates/layout/region--header.html.twig/`.

Comment: My template /themes/marinenat/templates/layout/region--header.html.twig is : <div class="nav">
  {% if content %}
    {{ content }}
  {% endif %}
</div>

Comment: Guess what happens when you change it to `<div class="nav foo"> {% if content %} {{ content }} {% endif %} </div>`?

Comment: Yes, exactly, but I'd like to add class dynamically

Comment: @antoine – This is the first time you tell us about some conditions. What conditions? Maybe you should add this to your question. I updated my answer to show you how to pass a string from PHP to Twig. You can easily make this to follow your desired logic – dynamically.

Comment: you're right. I'd like to add a class foo dynamically according the content type, just near "nav" class in the header